# changing an image to another one when clicking on a button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image displayed in my website. and I want to write a JavaScript code to change that image when clicking on a given button and I want to get another image displayed when clicking on another button so on and so forth. Let me show you how I have tried to solve this problem:

HTML:

```
<div class ="container image">
            <figure>
              <img src="alpaca/backgrounds/blue50.png"  id="picture" class ="show1" />
            </figure></div>
```

Javascript:

```
const image = document.getElementById("picture");

     function showImg() {
      image.src = "blue50.png";
      //hide previously shown image
      for ( i = 1; i < 18; i++) {
          var obj = document.getElementById( "picture" + i );
          if (obj != null)
              obj.className = 'hide1';
      }
      var obj = document.getElementById( "picture" + id );      
      if (obj != null)
          obj.className = 'show1';
    }
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:60px;
    left: -140px;
    
    
  }
   
  .image { 
    position:absolute;
    
    
  }
 
  .eye { 
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    
    
  }

  .mouth { 
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 8;
    
    
  }
  .nose { 
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 8;
    
    
  }

  .show1{display:block;}
  .hide1{display:none;}
  .leftButton {
    color: black;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:35px;
    font-family: 'sofia';
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color:rgb(252, 228, 228);
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -410px;
    left:200px;
    
  }
```

You see, what I need is for instance , when clicking on the button "blue60" of "Backgrounds" I should get another background image and this as to be the same for others buttons. Right now, when clicking on the button "blue60" I get nothing. Please , help me solve this problem.

```
<div id="Backgrounds" ><p class="para">Backgrounds</p>
        
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(1)" src="Alpaca/backgrounds/blue50" class="rightSubButton">Blue50</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(2)" src="Alpaca/backgrounds/blue60" class ="rightSubButton">Blue60</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(3)" src="Alpaca/backgrounds/blue70" class ="rightSubButton">Blue70</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(4)" class ="rightSubButton">Darkblue30</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(5)" class ="rightSubButton">Darkblue50</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(6)" class ="rightSubButton">Darkblue70</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(7)" class="rightSubButton">Green50</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(8)" class ="rightSubButton">Green60</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(9)" class ="rightSubButton">Green70</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(10)" class ="rightSubButton">Grey40</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(11)" class ="rightSubButton">Grey70</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(12)" class ="rightSubButton">Grey80</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(13)"class ="rightSubButton">Red50</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(14)"class ="rightSubButton">Red60</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(15)"class ="rightSubButton">Red70</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(16)"class ="rightSubButton">Yellow50</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(17)"class ="rightSubButton">Yellow60</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="showImg(18)"class ="rightSubButton">Yellow70</button>
      </div>
        <div id="Ears" ><p class="para">Ears</p>
          <button type="button" class="rightSubButton">Default</button>
          <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Tilt-backward</button>
          <button type="button" class ="rightSubButton">Tilt-forward</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `src` property of the desired `HTMLImageElement` in order to change its image:

```
const image = document.getElementById('...');

function showImg(number) {
  image.src = '...'; // Path or URL to image
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code,.. could you be more clear please @Eldar B. https://stackoverflow.com/users/4879856/eldar-b?

Comment: The `src` is what determines the image the `img` element will display. It holds the URI (path or URL) for the image you want to view. e.g. `'../images/img1.png'` or `'https://my-cdn.my-domain.com/images/img1.png'`.

Comment: The `...` is simply a placeholder for your actual element IDs and image sources... You don't actually need to put `'...'` there.

Comment: B https://stackoverflow.com/users/4879856/eldar-b , I changed my codes and that according to your advice . Still I did not fix the issue. What is wrong again?

Comment: @sabine can you post your current code in jsfiddle, GitHub or codeshare? The formatting in the comments is rather bad